# Indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly

Tags: c#, .net, telerik

So i have updated my Telerik dll's by dropping the new ones over the top and then cleaning my solution and rebuilding, to produce the following error:

Warning 3   The primary reference "Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Xaml" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly `"mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"` which has a higher version `"5.0.5.0"` than the version `"2.0.5.0"` in the current target framework.

I have googled lots and have found a few scenario's, but nothing  that really helped. I tried deleting reference and restarting visual studio, but nothing worked. I was hoping someone could give me some ideas to help diagnose/solve my problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project's target framework is obviously 2.0 and those components probably require the latest version of .NET framework.

You could try to set the target framework to a more recent one from your project's `Properties -> Application -> Target framework`.

Comment: Cheers Alex, i completely overlooked that. I just had to change the silverlight target to "silverlight 5" and job done.

Answer (score 0):

it means that you have other Dlls that reference those who were updated from version 2 to 5. 
Are you sure you updated all the necessary Dlls?