# Unable to run the application using VS2017

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I have a .Net application which has target framework of 3.5 
While debugging the code , i am facing the below error.

> The primary reference "xxx" could not be resolved because it has an
>   indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
>   which has a higher version "4.0.0.0" than the version "2.0.0.0" in the
>   current target framework.

I am running the application on VS2017.
How to rectify the error.

Comment: Go through the project references and replace that CLR4.0 assembly reference with one for 3.5 - and if that isn't available then you'll need to upgrade your project to .NET 4 (ideally at least 4.6.1).

Comment: i tried upgrading the project to .NET 4.0 but then another error poped up of "HTTP Error 500.24 - Internal Server Error"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394299/indirect-dependency-on-the-net-framework-assembly)